# Blazor Webassembly ASP.NET Core Hosted cannot authorize via Facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook, nginx, blazor, webassembly

I've got problem with my application. When I'm trying to authorize via Facebook on localhost - there's no problems, everything goes fine. After publishing my application authorization becames random... When you try to sign in via facebook there are two options:

- Infinity login display, after many login attemps one may be successfull
- You're authorized successfull

In project I use IdentityServer4 with default scaffolded Razor Pages. I think that problem may be in Blazor routing, because facebook response is interpreted by Blazor (but not always, it's random). When I got infinity login loop on one device, I can login without any problems on another device, sometimes clearing browser data helps, but not always. I know... it's very strange but much more frustrating. Below I attach screen from browser, where you can see that facebook callback is going to Blazor.

[Screenshot of URL from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLfof.jpg)

I suppose that it could be caused by Nginx configuration - because on localhost there's no problem with no metter if I'm using IIS or Kestrel. This is my Nginx site configuration:

```
server {
    server_name   izipass.pl www.izipass.pl;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://localhost:2020;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        add_header         Service-Worker-Allowed /;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/izipass.pl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/izipass.pl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.izipass.pl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = izipass.pl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name   izipass.pl www.izipass.pl;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I try to figure it out from few days and I looked for any answer over Internet, but none of them solved my problem. I want try to change base path of Blazor app, and move it "https://.../app" to unable Blazor routing at "/signin-facebook".

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Blazor app is intended to live as the fallback route, and invokes a static html page (index.html), when no other route is available.

So if you're getting a Blazor page loaded when you intended for an MVC controller or Api Controller to be invoked, that means that the **route could not be resolved.**

You could test this by removing Blazor entirely and verifying that signin-facebook now resolves to a 404 when supplying the exact same parameters as in your screenshot.

Ideally, you'll reserve a prefix like 'api' for all of your api actions so that there's no confusion between your client-side navigation and server actions.